# Can I deploy same Laravel project in main domain and subdomain?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have developed a news website project using laravel 8x for one domain(main domain) Can I use the same project in subdomain? Main domain project frontend will Bangla language and the subdomain project frontend will English. Is it possible? or do I have to install new Laravel apps for the subdomain project?

Also, database will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There of course you cant use different databases for same Laravel Project unless you make separate installation for each domain and its subdomain.

Indeed You can use localization in Laravel so you will not have to install 2 copies for the same app

More details about localization here : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization